# Python: is thread still running

Tags: python, multithreading

How do I see whether a thread has completed? I tried the following, but threads_list does not contain the thread that was started, even when I know the thread is still running.

```
import thread
import threading

id1 = thread.start_new_thread(my_function, ())
#wait some time
threads_list = threading.enumerate()
# Want to know if my_function() that was called by thread id1 has returned 

def my_function()
    #do stuff
    return
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The key is to start the thread using threading, not thread:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=my_function, args=())
t1.start()
```

Then use

```
z = t1.is_alive()
# Changed from t1.isAlive() based on comment. I guess it would depend on your version.
```

or

```
l = threading.enumerate()
```

You can also use join():

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=my_function, args=())
t1.start()
t1.join()
# Will only get to here once t1 has returned.
```

Comment: 2019 answer: use `is_alive` instead of `isAlive`; you will see a deprecation warning for the above answer.

Comment: @Tommy that is what my answer is all about i thought it important in this context so i posted it.

Comment: Just an **advice**: remember that `is_alive` also returns True if you still not have called `start` yet. If your program is complex and there is any condition to start your threat, you can put the program in a deadlock condition.

Answer (score 1):

You must start the thread by using `threading`.

```
id1 = threading.Thread(target = my_function)
id1.start()
```

And as of above if you don't have any `args` to mention you can just leave it blank.

To check your thread is alive or not you can use `is_alive()`

```
if id1.is_alive():
   print("Is Alive")
else:
   print("Dead")
```

**Note:** `isAlive()` is deprecated instead use `is_alive()`as per the python docs.

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Answer (score -2):

This is my code, It's not exactly what you asked, but maybe you will find it useful

```
import time
import logging
import threading

def isTreadAlive():
  for t in threads:
    if t.isAlive():
      return 1
  return 0


# main loop for all object in Array 

threads = []

logging.info('**************START**************')

for object in Array:
  t= threading.Thread(target=my_function,args=(object,))
  threads.append(t)
  t.start()

flag =1
while (flag):
  time.sleep(0.5)
  flag = isTreadAlive()

logging.info('**************END**************')
```

Comment: Your code is not explanatory. you must answer the question. If you like to suggest, just add that in comments. Oops you need more reputation to do that. Till then, try to find question which you feel your answers are *to the point* and explanatory.

Comment: the for-loop is incorrect. it returns 1 if one of threads isAlive.