# Create new thread if last thread is finished [Python 2.7]

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

I am new to Python threads. Basically, I have a QT based application designed in Python. The application has a button "Follow Trajectory", whenever I press this button, the robot starts moving. I noticed that robot is not following the exact trajectory.

[image]

The `move` command is being overwritten and robot receives only a few points. Below is the function, which gets executed when the button is pressed:

```
def move_robot(self):
    # points is an array of point
    for point in points:
        start_new_thread(self.robot.move, (point,))
```

Below is the `move` function from the controller:

```
def move(self, point):
    while True:
        self._robot_controller.move(point)
        current_location = self._robot_controller.location()
        if current_location - point < 0.0001:
            break
```

**My question is that how to create a new thread only if last thread is finished?**

Below is the complete code:

```
class RobotControllerWrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self._robot_controller = RobotController()

    def move(self, point):
        while True:
            self._robot_controller.move(point)
            current_location = self._robot_controller.location()
            if current_location - point < 0.0001:
                break

from thread import start_new_thread
from qt_gui.plugin import Plugin
from python_qt_binding.QtGui import QWidget, QPushButton

class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, context):

        super(MyPlugin, self).__init__(context)
        self.setObjectName('MyPlugin')

        self._widget = QWidget()
        self._vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._move_robot_button = QPushButton('Follow Trajectory')
        self._move_robot_button.clicked.connect(self.move_robot)
        self._vertical_layout.addWidget(self._move_robot_button)
        self._widget.setLayout(self._vertical_layout)
        self._widget.setObjectName('MyPluginUi')

        if context.serial_number() > 1:
            self._widget.setWindowTitle(self._widget.windowTitle() + (' (%d)' % context.serial_number()))
        context.add_widget(self._widget)

        self.robot = RobotControllerWrapper()

    def move_robot(self):
        # points is an array of point
        for point in points:
            start_new_thread(self.robot.move, (point,))
```

Apologize for the long post. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mind blocking at `for` loop in `move_robot`? You can use `join`. Otherwise you need to create a new thread for this `for` loop.

Comment: @Sraw: I think if I block `for` loop in the main application, the GUI is going to be unresponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you need to create a new thread for `move_robot`:

```
def move_robot(self):
    # points is an array of point
    def move_robot_thread(points):
        for point in points:
            thread = start_new_thread(self.robot.move, (point,))
            thread.join()
    start_new_thread(move_robot_thread, (points,))
```

BTW, I assume `start_new_thread` returns `Thread` object.

## update

```
def move_robot(self):
    from threading import Thread, start_new_thread
    # points is an array of point
    def move_robot_thread(points):
        for point in points:
            thread = Thread(target=self.robot.move, args=(point,))
            thread.start()
            thread.join()
    start_new_thread(move_robot_thread, (points,))
```

This is for you. I haven't tested, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. The thread is created from this `from thread import start_new_thread`. How to use `threading` package in the above suggested code?

Comment: Thanks a lot. `ImportError: cannot import name start_new_thread`. I think this should be `from thread import start_new_thread`. But I am wondering whether it is a good practice or not to use `thread` and `threading` packages together.

Answer (score 1):

In the definition in the methode move robot, you should add a "thread controller" to check if last running thread is over, before starting a new one.
Here is maybe a good tutorial, [Python: is thread still running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063963/python-is-thread-still-running)

In particular the method:

```
if last_thread.isAlive() ==  False:
    new_thread = start_new_thread(self.robot.move, (point,))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't test your code at this moment. But are you sure that, doing this will not affect UI? I don't want to make UI responsive while the time robot is moving.